# Как вставить видео, чтобы оно было во весь экран?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Как вставить видео, чтобы оно было во весь экран?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно видео задать размеры через CSS, например, поставив width: 100% и height: 100vh. Но нужно видео с соответствующим пропорциями, чтобы оно правильно покрывало 100% экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ взят с официального источника [developer.mozilla.org: Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)

> Давайте рассмотрим этот  элемент:
>
> ```
> <video controls id="myvideo">
>   <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
>   <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
> </video>
> ```
>
> Мы можем перевести это видео в полноэкранный режим режим следующими
>   скриптами:
>
> ```
> var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
> if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
>   elem.requestFullscreen();
> } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
>   elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
> } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
>   elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
> }
> ```
>
> Движек Gecko автоматически добавляет CSS правила к элементу, чтобы растянуть
>   его для заполнения экрана: `"width: 100%; height: 100%"`. WebKit этого
>   не делает; вместо этого происходит центрирование полноэкранного
>   элемента по размеру вероятной черной области. Для получения
>   необходимого полноэкранного поведения в движке WebKit, необходимо
>   самостоятельно добавить собственные `"width: 100%; height: 100%;"` CSS
>   правила к элементу:
>
> ```
> :-webkit-full-screen #myvideo {
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
> }
> ```

- перевод собственный, почти дословный

Answer (score 0):

если html 5 то так

```
  <video autoplay loop muted class="bgvideo" id="bgvideo">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
```